# How to write xpath which has ::before and ::after (selenium)

Tags: selenium, xpath

Line 1 ->

```
<input _ngcontent-huh-c120="" name="options" id="line" type="radio" 
ng-reflect-name="options" ng-reflect-model="0" ng-reflect-value="0" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" xpath="1">

Line 2-> ::before
Line 3-> ::after
```

I am trying to click on a radio button called line. I have 3 lines in html line 1,2 & 3. When I hover over all 3 lines all of them has exact same xpath
so its getting confuse on which xpath to select.

I tried `//*[@id='line']` but its not working. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate using xpath indexing, like below :

for first this should work.

```
(//*[@id='line'])[1]
```

for second this should work.

```
(//*[@id='line'])[2]
```

and so on..

Comment: I tried both but its not working. Tried  @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='line'][1]") and also tried  @FindBy(xpath = " //input[contains(@type, 'radio') and @id = 'line'][1]") (with and without [1] but doesn't work. Not finding my element.

Comment: @Sam1977 : if page URL is public, please share, or else share the page resource here with us.